# Woocommerce display status filtered orders made by customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hope you are doing great.
As subject says I´m trying to display a function in a specific page in Wordpress through shortcode but returns blank.

Any idea what´s wrong?

```
function statics_customer_dash($has_orders)
{
    $customer_orders = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => - 1,
        'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value' => get_current_user_id() ,
        'post_type' => wc_get_order_types() ,
        'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses()) ,
        'post_status' => array(
            'wc-completed'
        ) ,
    ));

    $total_orders = count($customer_orders);

    if ($has_orders)
    {
        echo 'n° orders: ' . $total_orders;
    }

};

// Register shortcode
add_shortcode('stats_each_customer', 'statics_customer_dash');
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/: "Note that the function called by the shortcode should _never_ produce an output of any kind. Shortcode functions should _return_ the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode."

Comment: And what made you think your function would get a `$has_orders` parameter passed?

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanks for your reply!
WOW you´ve just nailed, now I´m totally lost on this...
any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Comment: If you want to pass in parameters, you need to use https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Handling_Attributes